# Unable to install pyarrow - ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyarrow

I am using python v 3.8 , numpy-1.24.4 pandas-2.0.3, cmake 3.27.3 on Windows 10 - 64 bit
However ,when I try to install pyarrow using

```
pip install pyarrow
```

I get the error below `File "<string>", line 299, in _run_cmake RuntimeError: Not supported on 32-bit Windows [end of output]`

Updated the list here

```
    sys.version: 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
sys.executable: c:\users\user\projects\development\scripts\python.exe
sys.getdefaultencoding: utf-8
sys.getfilesystemencoding: utf-8
locale.getpreferredencoding: cp1252
sys.platform: win32
sys.implementation:
  name: cpython
'cert' config value: Not specified
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: None
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: None
pip._vendor.certifi.where(): c:\users\user\projects\development\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\certifi\cacert.pem
pip._vendor.DEBUNDLED: False
vendored library versions:
  CacheControl==0.12.11
  colorama==0.4.6
  distlib==0.3.6
  distro==1.8.0
  msgpack==1.0.5
  packaging==21.3
  platformdirs==3.8.1
  pyparsing==3.1.0
  pyproject-hooks==1.0.0
  requests==2.31.0
  certifi==2023.05.07
  chardet==5.1.0
  idna==3.4
  urllib3==1.26.16
  rich==13.4.2 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  pygments==2.15.1
  typing_extensions==4.7.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  resolvelib==1.0.1
  setuptools==68.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  six==1.16.0
  tenacity==8.2.2 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  tomli==2.0.1
  webencodings==0.5.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
Compatible tags: 30
  cp38-cp38-win32
```

Unable to figure out the compatibilty. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is supposed to appear on Windows 32 bits (https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/de8df23a8cd9737b4df5bb1b68fc12a54f252d0d/python/setup.py#L298-L300):

```
            if sys.platform == 'win32':
                if not is_64_bit:
                    raise RuntimeError('Not supported on 32-bit Windows')
```

Are you sure you are using Windows 64 bits for building PyArrow?

What version of Pyarrow is pip trying to build?

There are wheels built for Windows 64 bits for Python3.8. Can you share the list of tags supported on your pip?

```
pip debug --verbose
```

Comment: Updated pip debug -- verbose. It seems like 32 bit. But I am using 64 bit Windows - C:\Users\user>wmic os get osarchitecture
OSArchitecture
64-bit

Comment: It does seem you installed Python 32 bits. Could you install Python 64 bits?

Comment: I verified further my environment variable was the issue. I created a new environment variable on Python 64 bit and it worked. Thank you